# What does the xunit console output (for a failing test) actually mean?

Tags: c#, xunit

On the linux command line I created a simple xunit test project with :

`$ dotnet new xunit`

In the file UnitTest1.cs , created as part of the xunit project template, I entered the following **simplest possible failing test** with a single line `Assert.Equal(1,2);` ... like so :

```
namespace trash;

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        
        Assert.Equal(1,2);
      
    }
   
}
```

**The output of the failing test is :**

```
Starting test execution, please wait...   
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.  
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.43]     trash.UnitTest1.Test1 [FAIL]   
  Failed trash.UnitTest1.Test1 [4 ms]   
  Error Message:   
   Assert.Equal() Failure   
Expected: 1  
Actual:   2  
  Stack Trace:  
     at trash.UnitTest1.Test1() in     
 [pathtoMyProjects/Projects/trash/UnitTest1.cs:line 9   
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)  
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)  
   
Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:     0, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: < 1 ms - trash.dll (net7.0)
```

**I have two simple questions:**

1. What does [xUnit.net 00:00:00.43] mean? -- specifically what does this number 43 represent ?
2. Why do we see this Stack Trace ?  -- specifically , where was this exception thrown, who caught it , and what are we supposed to do with this ?

I searched stackoverflow, xunit documentation, and google -- but it was surprisingly hard to get answers to these simple questions. Can anyone please answer these questions -- or point me to a resource where this output is explained.

Comment: I would assume the `00:00:00.43` refers to the time the test took to run in milliseconds - an assumption supported by `[4 ms]` - and as to _Why do we see this Stack Trace?_ - why would you *not* want to see a stack trace in a failing test?

Comment: @stuartd thanks for commmenting. Yes it does look like time the test took.  
On the stack trace however: if you look at the trace, it is not referering to my code --- it is about some exception raised in the xunit framework itself , which has no informational value for me. Don't know why it is there and what does it mean.

Comment: The very first entry in the stack trace shows your code: _at trash.UnitTest1.Test1() in pathtoMyProjects/Projects/trash/UnitTest1.cs:line_ the rest of the stack entries are the xUnit code that invoked your test.

Comment: @Flydog57 ... ah thanks .... yes its there. For some reason my eyes glossed over that first line and got worked up by those scary lines coming from the xunit framework.

Comment: The Assert methods in xunit throw an exception when the assertion fails. The stack trace allows you to find exactly where the assertion was. The test runner catches the exceptions and reports the results.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins Thank you for further clarification. Much appreciated.